# Generating all possible directed acyclic graphs

Tags: java, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to enumerate all possible DAGs with `n` vertices. I know there are a lot of them and I'm assuming `n` is very small (3 to 5). I was wondering if there is a way to enumerate them. My initial solution is create them by the number of edges `m` . Considering structures with 0 edges then those with 1 ...etc. The cases of `m=0` or `m=n(n-1)/2` is well studies (1 and `n!` respectively). However, it is unclear to me how many DAGs are there with `1<m<n(n-1)/2` edges.

**Update:** As some users think it is broad topic I will try to narrow it down to generating undirected graphs. Because given an undirected graph `G` with `m` edges there are `2^|m|` orientations and I have implemented a method to do this while checking acyclicity. The question in another way: *How to generate all possible undirected graphs for `n` vertices ?*

Comment: downvoters: please advice me on how to make it more specific !

Comment: This sounds more like a maths problem than a coding problem.

Comment: @immibis IT is a coding problem. Regardless of how many DAGs are there , the issue is how to generate them in code.

Comment: Graph theory *is* a branch of mathematics...

Answer (score 2):

Because undirected graphs a just a set of edges, if I understand you second question, you are asking for code that generates all the possible sets of edges. Is that right?

```
void getAllEdgeSets(List<Edge> currentEdges, List<Edge> remainingEdges) {
    if (remainingEdges.isEmpty()) {
        processSet(currentEdges);
    } else {
        Edge edge = remainingEdges.remove(0);
        getAllEdgeSets(currentEdges, remainingEdges);
        currentEdges.add(edge);
        getAllEdgeSets(currentEdges, remainingEdges);
        currentEdges.remove(edge);
    }
}
```

this is called with an empty list to start with:

```
getAllEdgeSets(Collections.EMPTY_LIST, edges);
```

You could also turn this into a source for a stream so that you can process as you go (potentially in parallel):

```
streamAllGraphs(5).filter(Graph::isAcyclic).forEach(...);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am implementing something similar. Yes the goal is to get all undirected graphs with m edges for every m between 0 and n(n-1)/2. For every m there are (n choose m) undirected graphs. Your code outputs subset of these (tested it for (0,1)(0,2)(1,2) which represents all undirected edges for n=3). Thanks again.

Comment: It also should be trivial to change it to be directed edges. The Edge class needs a source and destination vertex and then the method to generate all the edges generates in both directions.

Comment: Also note that this is pretty inefficient if you are just going to filter out cyclic graphs. You could change it to filter remainingEdges for only those that don't cause cycles before recursing.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a DFS solution to the problem of generating the graphs, something like:

```
graph(g) {  // g is current graph; start with an empty graph
  find set V of vertices in g
  if V is not empty
    emit g
  for every v in V {
    find set V' of vertices not in g
    for every v' in V' {
      g' = g with new edge from v to v'
      graph(g')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems to exclude all the graphs that include two edges going to the same vertex.

Comment: I stared at it awhile before posting thinking the same, but convinced myself otherwise. There is one bug with the initial condition (needs a starting edge).